# Identify and replace capacitor "FP12K 79AJ 271 16"

Tags: capacitor

Unfortunately a capacitor got knocked off from a mainboard. The mainboard is an AsRock Z370 Extreme4 (see [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/Z370%20Extreme4/index.asp)).

The capacitor is labelled as:

```
FP12K
79AJ
271
16
```

I want to replace it, but I am not sure what capacitor would be equivalent. What I found out is that it must be a "Nichicon 12K Black Cap". I think the "16" means 16 Volt, but I don't know what "79AJ" and "271" means.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find the datasheet for this exact capacitor from Nichicon, maybe these FP12K are ASRock specific, but one for the [RHT series](https://www.nichicon.co.jp/english/series_items/catalog_pdf/e-rht.pdf) which has similar markings.

[image]

This means the capacitor in question is rated for 16V and has a capacity of 270uF.

Comment: Do you know why the number is 271 instead of 270?

Comment: @Tintenfisch It stands for 27*10^1.

Comment: Exact cap is `CAP PL 270UF/16V 8*11.5-12K-B NICHICON/FP-016RE271M-KBCG-BHU`. I still accepted your answer because it was helpful to identify capacity and voltage.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find it out:

```
CAP PL 270UF/16V 8*11.5-12K-B NICHICON/FP-016RE271M-KBCG-BHU
```

Left (Pin 2) is GND and right (Pin 1) is +12V:

[image]

Comment: Wow [this](https://i.imgur.com/ssFpbXE.png) is really confusing. Suggest double checking with a voltmeter.

Comment: Sorry, always the same with me. I fixed the typo. The left pin (Pin 2) is GND, I double checked it with a voltmeter and added a screenshot to clearify.